# Is it possible to determine irregularity in the primary key of SQLite Database

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a Table in SQLite Named `UserAccessLevels`, and Column name of the primary key is `No`. The sequence of the primary key is `0,1,3,4` in the primary key `2` is missing. Is it possible to find this irregular primary key `2` by running any query in SQLite Database.

Comment: Probably not. Most databases that use any autonumbering, will have skipped numbers due to rollbacks or the record could have been deleted. NEVER assume there will be no gaps in the numbering of a database table.

Comment: @HLGEM Oh Thank you.......... :)

Comment: Is it possible to find the missing value? Yes. Is it necessary? No. Don't bother. The ***only*** requirement for a (generated) primary key is, that it is unique. It dos not matter if you have a gap in the numbers or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to check for the existence of the respective next row (with the special case of the last row):

```
SELECT No + 1
FROM UserAccessLevels
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM UserAccessLevels AS T2
                  WHERE T2.No = UserAccessLevels.No + 1)
  AND No != (SELECT MAX(No)
             FROM UserAccessLevels);
```

(When there is a gap larger than one, this returns only the start of the gap.)

Comment: Hey Thank you very much.. It totally worked, Could you please explain `SELECT 1 FROM UserAccessLevels AS T2 WHERE T2.No = UserAccessLevels.No + 1` this part of the code please. I could not understand what the query is doing

Comment: See the page I linked to.